# Delete the lines containing a specific word (letter and number)

Tags: bash

I have a file as the following. I want to delete all lines the consisting `H2`, `H4`, `H1` and `H6` characters. For this aim, I used this command: `grep -v "H1" input.gro > output.gro`. But this command also deletes the lines including `H11` and `H10`. And after 10000th row, it doesn't deletes the lines. How can I fixed my command? P.S: I should preserve the spacing between the columns in the output file.

```
XYX    C1    1   3.339   0.189   
XYX   H11    2   3.376   0.253   
XYX    H2    3   3.276   0.260  
XYX   H10    4   3.262   0.127   
XYX    C1    5   3.443   0.115  
XYX    H4    6   3.491   0.193   
XYX    H1    7   3.393   0.048  
XYX    B3    8   3.552   0.057  
XYX    H6    9   3.512   0.026
...    ..    .   .....   .....
XYX    H1 9998   3.294   4.293
XYX    H2 9999   3.379   4.287 
XYX    H310000   3.377   4.151  
XYX   H1110001   0.217   3.143  
XYX    N110002   0.299   3.109   
XYX   H1010003   0.318   3.022   
XYX    C410004   0.277   3.096
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to hack it is to add a space after the expression. To handle multiple different characters, you can use a character class which represents one of multiple characters in your expression.

```
grep -v "H[1246] " input.gro > output.gro
```

The cleaner way to do it is to use word boundaries which are less fragile and allow grep to match the pattern only if it forms a "word" where word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric characters and underscore.

```
grep -v "\bH[1246]\b" input.gro > output.gro
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I delete all lines the consisting H2, H4, H1 and H6 by one command?

Comment: @erhan, There must be something specific about the 1000th row that causes a problem, or the nature of your input changes after that row. You have to identify what that is.

Comment: This is an ouput file of a program. I have not changed it. After 10000th row (not 1000th), the command doesn't delete the lines including H2, H4, H1 and H6. Because those lines are next to the lines of another column. That is a big problem.

Comment: @erhan, It sounds like you need to modify the program that generates this output so that it correctly delimits its fields with a minimum of one space. It would be a tremendously terrible hack for a post-processing program to take the output and separate it based on the character count of the merged column, even though it is technically possible.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is a very readable approach that requires no hacks.

```
awk '$2!~/H[1246]$/' input.gro > output.gro
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep, at least some of them has `-w` to match only a whole word.  So you could do

```
grep -v -w "H1" input.gro > output.gro
```

or all those matches together

```
grep -v -w "H[1246]" input.gro > outout.gro
```

Given your edit about having problems when the chars from the next column run into the H1 column perhaps you can try this:

```
egrep -v "^.{7}H[1246]"
```

to anchor it to the start of the line, ignore the first 7 characters then make sure you have one of the H values you want